# Javascript: wait loop for jquery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ajax like as below:

```
$.get('/api/get-data)
.then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

And i want write a loop to get data, like this:

```
while (true) {
    $.get('/api/lastbids/' + auctionId)
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

I want set delay between every request, i can use `setinterval` but i want when get response finished, after 500ms send another request for data.

Comment: Use promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise so you can track whether you got the response or not.

Comment: @divakar what is `.then()` in jQuery?

Comment: Create a function to get `/api/lastbids/`, than in callback delay 500ms, than call same function again.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Since he want it to be deferred, i suggested a custom promise function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple function recursion with a recurring `setTimeout`:

```
function getBidsLoop () {
  $.get('/api/lastbids/' + auctionId).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
    setTimeout(getBidsLoop, 500); // << Recursive call
  });
}


getBidsLoop (); // Start
```

Comment: i used your code, and set 1 sec delay in backend (/api/las..) but only work in first time, please check it https://i.imgur.com/Xvc0gG5.png

Comment: @Masoud92m fixed. Sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks for each request

```js
var firstRequest = function(callback) {
      // some random endpoint for result
      $.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/', function(data) {
        callback(data);
      }).fail(function() {
        callback(false);
      });
    },
    secondRequest = function(callback) {
      // some random endpoint for result
      $.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/', function(data) {
        callback(data);
      }).fail(function() {
        callback(false);
      });
    };


// first, run first request, wait for response, then run second request. finally grab both request's responses. 
firstRequest(function(firstResult){
  if (firstResult) {
    // you can wrap the code below with setTimeout if you want
    secondRequest(function(secondResult) {
      console.log(firstResult, secondResult);
    });
  }
});
```